# Is the interval $ds^2$ NOT invariant under translation in an inhomogenous space?

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

In the [Chapter 9 Symmetries, Section 9.1 The Killing vectors](http://www.roma1.infn.it/teongrav/VALERIA/TEACHING/RELATIVITA_GENERALE/AA2010_11/simmetrie.pdf) (page 101) are Killing vectors defined such that an infinitesimal translation along the vector keep the line element invariant.

It means that if the Killing vector equation doesn't have a solution, the space is not homogeneous.

My doubt is: If the space is not homogeneous, the line element is not an invariant. This contradicts that scalars are invariant under any general coordinate transform.

Where am I wrong? Are tensors not covariant in an inhomogenous space?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It matters of two different concepts.

1)
The transformation under which the geometry, i.e. the spacetime interval $ds$, is invariant is expressed infinitesimally as a motion in the direction of a Killing vector $K^\mu$. The vector $K^\mu$ is said to generate the isometry.

2)
A scalar is invariant under a general coordinate transformation. In a coordinate transformation the physical point in spacetime does not change, but it is renamed. Similar considerations hold for tensors. Any combination of tensors, which results in a scalar, is invariant under a general coordinate transformation.

Answer (score 1):

As a simpler example, consider the scalar field $\phi(x)=\sin x$ defined on the line. A change of coordinates $x \mapsto x'=x+\epsilon$ does change the value of $\phi$ when we compare $\sin 0$ with $\sin\epsilon$. However, it doesn't change the value of $\phi$ when keep the point the same but merely rename the point. The latter is what we mean when we say that scalars are invariant.

Comment: Thanks for that example sir. But I still have a confusion. A system is invariant under Translation of coordinate if the space is translationaly symmetric (Homogeneous space). Thus, in an in-homogeneous space scalars doesn't remain invariant under any translation of coordinate. Am I right with my statement or is there any terrible misconception I made?

Comment: @walber97 There are two types of translations. One of the coordinates that only renames points, but doesn't change anything physically. The other is of the system, such as lifting up a weight. Since metric refers to spacetime, the interval is invariant under the translation of coordinates. However, if you physically move the system to a different place, the interval there might be different, but it would not be a translation of the interval.